# Translating script from Spanish to English

Tags: function, translation

I was hoping to get some help with a project. Some time ago at work, I was tasked to make a kiosk report that runs on raspberry pis. Part of this report was a javascript file that determines what webpages will be displayed.

It works great, but the .js report is in Spanish, since I worked with an international team. Just for the sake of neatness, I have been translating the Spanish parts, but I have hit a snag. The function in the report reads as:

function establecerPaginas(Paginas)

(I can translate the rest of the file and it works fine)

As far as I can tell, the English should be setPages() but if I put that as the function name, the webpage will not display. Is that the wrong command? Do I need to do something extra to change the function name?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What does "that doesn't seem to work" mean?

Comment: As in, if I change establecerPaginas() to setPages(), the webpage no longer displays when I boot. 

I edited the original post for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the name of the function, you also need to change all the places where that same function gets called..

Same would apply for the parameters for that function.

Comment: For the file I am working on, it is actually only called once. This is the entire file in a working state:

function establecerPaginas(pages)
 { page[0] = "url"; return pages; }

 I would just like the English version of whatever "function establecerPaginas()" is.

If it is getting called somewhere outside of the file it is in, I would have to find out. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: there is no "english version", you can rename it to anything, but then you need to do the same `rename` on all the places where this function is called, and match the names...